# Selección tipo dropdown en un input

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap

Buenas, quisiera hacer que al hacer click sobre esta barra de opciones que tengo ahora y elija una, se cambie el valor por defecto que trae ese boton.

```
<label for="numero_telefono">NÚMERO DE TELEFÓNO *</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
                                098 &nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">097</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">096</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">099</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input id="numero_telefono" type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono"
                               placeholder="123456" value="{{Input::old('telefono')}}">
                        @if($errors->has('telefono'))<p class="msg-error">{{$errors->first('telefono')}}</p>@endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es capturar el valor del elemento al que le das click y asignar ese valor al campo donde necesitas que se muestre, así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-item").click(function(){
    var valor = $(this).text();
    
    $(".dropdown-toggle").html(valor + '&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>')
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label for="numero_telefono">NÚMERO DE TELEFÓNO *</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
                                098 &nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">097</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">096</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">099</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input id="numero_telefono" type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono"
                               placeholder="123456" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Te aclaro que en este ejemplo quité el cogido de la plantilla (condición y value) para que de pronto no generara conflictos ya que en este ejemplo no se está instalando Blade, Saludos

Comment: Genial! Funciono perfectamente, gracias!